# ETH-BROWNIE install issue - windows - pipx

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding, brownie, pipx

So I am trying to install eth-brownie via `pipx` as recommended, this on Windows.
I tried everything also multiple re-installs of EVERYTHING including python.
This one error just isn't fixable for me and googling this doesn't help.

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\solidity> python -m pipx install eth-brownie

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 779, in cli
    return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command
    return commands.install(
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
    venv.install_package(
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
    subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
    print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to <undefined>
```

This last python install was via Microsoft store, don't ask me why, but this error is the same if I download python via the normal way.

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.
Works fine on my laptop, but it's an old and slow one so need it on PC.

Comment: You may need to make your terminal capable of handling unicode: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line).

Comment: Hi Snakecharmerb, 

Thank you for your reply!
However I did not get any further.
I installed win-unicode-console via pip, but got the same error as before.
Also tried exporting, editing & importing the file from registry but to no avail.

Any more ideas are very welcome

Comment: I faced a similar error and managed to install eth-brownie successfully. A similar question was asked and I wrote my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891172/how-to-resolve-this-unicodeencodeerror-while-installing-eth-brownie-on-windows10/71976218#71976218

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I just did it using pip instead of pipx:

`python -m pip install eth-brownie`

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
It might be possible yes, but you wont get the env handy part from using with pipx.
So it might be possible, but you will need to put in more work I heard into managing your envs.
Or is this incorrect?

Comment: ps got an error trying it with pip as well

Comment: Sorry, if that doesn't work I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with python version 3.10.2
Downgraded python to version 3.9.2, installation of eth-brownie using pipx works fine.

Answer (score 0):

"UnicodeEncodeError" is not the real error. It is encoding error when the script was trying to print the real error.

To fix this fake error,

```
vi "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py"
change from
   with pip_error_file.open("w") as pip_error_fh:
to
   with pip_error_file.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as pip_error_fh:
```

Then run your install script again, and you will see the REAL error.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is uninstall the python3.10 pipx venvs installation of eth-brownie.  Make sure you also already have python3.9 installed on your computer.  Then reinstall eth-brownie using python3.9

```
pipx uninstall eth-brownie
python3.9 -m pip install --user pipx
python3.9 -m pipx ensurepath
python3.9 -m pipx install eth-brownie
```

to add libraries to your eth-brownie pipx venvs

```
python3.9 -m pipx inject eth-brownie playsound
```